# Return JSON for objects related with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have built an API for my portfolio site with the Django REST Framework. I want to show the stack I used for each project so I made a `Skill` model for things like Python, Javascript etc..

My `Project` model has a `ManyToManyField` for choosing each technology I used.

This works great however I want the JSON I get back to contain the whole object for each `Skill`. Currently I just get an array of the ids.

**Here are my models**

```
 class Skill(models.Model): 
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   image = models.FileField(upload_to="skills/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['svg'])])
 
   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
 
 
 class Project(models.Model):
   project_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="projects/")
   project_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   project_stack = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.project_title
```

**My endpoint returns the following JSON for each project:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "project_image": "/media/projects/161044437967.png",
    "project_title": "Example Project",
    "project_stack": [
        1,            
        4,
        14
    ]
}
```

I'd like `project_stack` to return the entire object rather than the `id`s.

**Desired output**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "project_image": "/media/projects/161044437967.png",
    "project_title": "Example Project",
    "project_stack": [
        {"id": 1, "title": "Python", "image": "/media/skills/161044437967.png"},
        {"id": 4, "title": "Javascript", "image": "/media/skills/160444437964.png"},
        {"id": 14, "title": "CSS", "image": "/media/skills/161044422965.png"},
    ]
}
```

**serializers.py**

```
 class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model = Project
     fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
 @api_view(['GET'])
 def project_detail(request, slug):
   project = get_object_or_404(Project, project_slug=slug)
   serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many=False)
   return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was quite simple

I just needed to add `depth = 1` to my serializer

```
 class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model = Project
     fields = '__all__'
     depth = 1
```